# side length of trapezoid after cut

Tags: geometry

Given a symetrical trapezoid with a bottom length (a) and a top lenght (b) and a height (h)  that I would like to cut off at a certain height (h'), how do I calculate the new top lenght (b')?

[image: symetrical trapezoid, given, wanted]

Answer (score 4):

Let $w$ be the required width. The area of the **bottom** part of the trapezoid is $$\frac{1}{2}(a+w)h'.$$ 
The area of the **top** part of the trapezoid is 
$$\frac{1}{2}(w+b)(h-h').$$ 
Together, they make up the **whole** trapezoid, which has area 
$$\frac{1}{2}(a+b)h.$$ 
After multiplying by $2$, we obtain the equation
$$(a+w)h'+(w+b)(h-h')=(a+b)h.\tag{$1$} $$
This equation is linear in $w$, and not difficult to solve.

For fun, we solve the equation. Things will look nicer if we write $p$ instead of $h'$, and $q$ instead of $h-h'$. Then $h=p+q$. Equation $(1)$ becomes
$$(a+w)p+(w+b)q=(a+b)(p+q).$$
A little algebra now gives
$$w=\frac{qa+pb}{p+q}=\frac{q}{p+q}a+\frac{p}{p+q}b.\tag{$2$}$$
Note the beautiful symmetry revealed by the change of notation. Note also that $w$ is a **weighted average** of $a$ and $b$, with weights $\frac{q}{p+q}$ and $\frac{p}{p+q}$. If one thinks about it for a while, the formula $(2)$ becomes geometrically self-evident.

**Remark:** Note that nowhere did we use the assumption that the trapezoid is *symmetrical*. We get exactly the same value of $w$ for non-symmetrical trapezoids.

Comment: +1 for the extra bonus of supporting asymmarical trapezoids and for the detailed deduction.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
So ,now  $$\frac{a-b}{2h}=\frac{x}{h-h^'}$$
And your answer will be $b+2x$

Comment: So the actual equation would be $$b'=b + \frac{2(a-b)(h-h')}{2h}$$ which can be simplified to $$b'=b + \frac{(a-b)(h-h')}{h}$$
Is this correct?